# I can open a Debian installation DVD but I can't boot the laptop from it

Tags: debian

I recently download a DVD from http://cdimage.debian.org/debian-cd/7.6.0/amd64/iso-dvd/debian-7.6.0-amd64-DVD-1.iso and I have an old Toshiba laptop which is running old Debian system on it.

After I burn a DVD for above ISO, I try to open it from the target laptop and it works fine.  But after I set the laptop to boot from CD/DVD, it can never boot up and fallback to the original GRUB in the laptop.

Does anyone know if it is due to I burned this DVD with a tool from Microsoft which originally used to burn Windows installation disk?

Thanks!

Comment: How did you create the disk after downloading the ISO?

Comment: @ECarterYoung, in Windows 8.1, I just right click the ISO file and burn it to the DVD.

Answer (score 1):

There is a list of steps which would be best :-

1. Figure out if the MD5SUM or better yet the SHA256SUM is same as the DVD. If those are identical to each other we go to next step. You could use something like http://pank.org/blog/2012/08/sha256sum-for-windows.html to verify the sha256sum.
2. Look at what sort of media you are using, if you are going to be using cheap media then while burning the ISO file, burn it at a slower rate. Burning at a slower rate does ensure that every bit is written.
3. If you have BIOS, just see what options are there. There are as many BIOS manufacturers as there are laptop manufacturers hence cannot say but the best would be to ensure that there are no conflicts with other settings.
4. Lastly, all said and done, if it is not working, try using the media in other laptop/desktop as well. This will tell you if the problem is in the media itself or it is an issue at the laptop itself.

You could try 4. before going to 1. as well just to know if the media and the .ISO file in it is good or not.

Comment: Thank you @shirish. Here comes my results: #1, I have verified before I burned the disc; #2, I used a disc in same box as this one on the same PC and burned another Windows 8.1 installation disc and works fine; #3, I believe the BIOS has been correctly setup and I have verified it many times. I also used manual select during boot up. No luck; #4, I will verify this tonight and update this comment.